# NSM explication for 'left'?

Tags: semantics, natural-semantic-metalanguage

How would the NSM explicate the word 'left'? As in, 'the table is to my left'.

I just cannot think of any way to do it using the current 65 primes.

Comment: You can define compass directions based on the Sun's movements, and then define 'left' as toward the East when you face South, etc.  (but NSM sentences are a real chore).

Comment: @aml You'd also need to know which hemisphere you're in, which you'd need the stars or a map to define. So yeah, a lot of work...

Comment: @amI Some cultures/languages do use compass based directions rather than left/right, but for those who do use left/right directions, it's surely based on our left/right hands.

Answer (score 3):

Although I've seen several NSM researchers discuss the concepts of "left" and "right" in relation to the semantic prime SIDE, I haven't seen any give a full explication for them. I don't think it's really that complex though, so I'll give it a go. I'll use a few semantic molecules; you can see how "hands" can be defined using primes in ["Natural Semantic Metalanguage: The state of the art" by Goddard, page 24](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/286033897_1_Natural_Semantic_Metalanguage_The_state_of_the_art). To start, I'll define left and right hands using three prominent actions:

> right hand =
>   (a) someone can use one hand to write
>     many people use this hand
>     a few people use the other hand
>   (b) someone can use one hand to pick up a small thing
>     many people use this hand
>     a few people use the other hand
>   (c) someone can use one hand to eat
>     many people use this hand
>     a few people use the other hand
>
> left hand =
>   (a) someone can use one hand to write
>     a few people use this hand
>     many people use the other hand
>   (b) someone can use one hand to pick up a small thing
>     a few  people use this hand
>     many people use the other hand
>   (c) someone can use one hand to eat
>     a few people use this hand
>     many people use the other hand

I think in English/modern Anglo culture writing, picking up, and eating are probably the most salient images for our hands, but in other cultures maybe the hand you hold your weapon in, or the hand you use for defecating is more significant.

So from these definitions for the left hand and right hand, we can derive the definitions for the sides/directions themselves:

> X is on my left side =
>   my left hand is on one side of me
>   X is on the same side of me as my left hand

And further extensions to general relative directions are possible:

> X is on the left of Y =
>   X is on one side of Y
>   I see that X is on the left side of Y

Comment: This is not helpful. There is no way of anyone telling whether the hand they use to eat with is the same hand that other people use to eat with, given that the only way to differentiate them is that more poeple eat with one of these. You need to distinguish between them before you are able to differentiate between them in accordance with your definition.

Comment: @Araucaria Sorry, I don't really understand your point. Something can be distinguished without it having a label. People have two hands. In aggregate more use one hand to eat than the other. That provides enough to define "right hand" and "left hand" in NSM.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Your definition pre-assumes that there is something inherently different about each of a person's two hands, and then assigns a label on the basis of which of the already identified hands most people use to do what. If that was all that was required, the question would be trivial. However, the 'meat' of the question is surely What are the attributes by which left and right (hands, for example) can be distinguished in the first place?

Comment: The answer to this puzzle is easy for earth-bound objects as long as they have both a top and a bottom and a front and a back (so problem solved). Otherwise it would be nigh on impossible.

Comment: @Araucaria Well there is something inherently different between a person's two hands: their chirality. The question is kind of trivial, which is probably why NSM researchers haven't bothered giving full explications before.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Chirality is very problematic philisophically and semantically. It's hard to distinguish chirally different objects without using combinations of tterms like left and right, top and bottom, front and back etc. Isn't that the point of the question?

Comment: @Araucaria It would indeed be difficult to define these things from first principles alone, but the NSM approach is free to define words through their human users and cultures. The words I'm defining here aren't contextless chiralities, but specifically English words about humans and their left and right sides. These definitions would have to be altered for other human cultures, let alone sentient worms.